# AWS SDK V2 Java DynamoDB AutoGenerate Id field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

In V1 SDK for AWS DynamoDB, we could create auto generated Ids using this annotation:

com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey;

I am using the V2 dynamoDB enhanced client and I cannot find an equivalent of this annotation, only see DynamoDbAutoGeneratedTimestampAttribute for timestamps.

Without this I have to generate the field using:  `(UUID.randomUUID().toString())`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
        <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is my model class.

```
 @Data
 @Builder
 @AllArgsConstructor
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @DynamoDbBean
 public class Person {

    private String id;
    private String personName;


    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    @DynamoDbAttribute(value = "id") // How to autogenerate this? 
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @DynamoDbAttribute(value = "personName")
    public String personName() {
        return personName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that is something that the Enhanced Client currently lacks. You can add your input to the feature request on GitHub:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1919